# left join issue with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables and trying to join both of them based on primary and foreign key.But the problem is that in second table the foreign key has multiple duplicate rows.

Structure :-

1 Table - category

```
catid   catname
1       AAA
2       BBB
3       CCC
```

2 Table - answers

```
ansid    catid     userid
1        1         9
2        1         9
3        2         9
4        2         6
```

The result should be

```
userid    catid   catname   present in answers table
null       1         AAA       no
6          2         BBB       yes
null       3         CCC       no
```

My query is

```
    SELECT a.userid, c.catid,c.catname, 
case when sum(a.catid is not null) > 0 
then 'yes' else 'no' end as present_in_answers_table 
from answers a left join 
category c  on c.catid = a.catid 
where  (a.userid = 6) group by c.catid
```

But it is not returning the results what I want.It returns only one row that is

```
userid    catid   catname   present in answers table    
6          2         BBB       yes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to switch the order of the joins, so you keep everything in the `category` table and then move the `where` condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT a.userid, c.catid, c.catname, 
       (case when count(a.catid) > 0 then 'yes' else 'no'
        end) as present_in_answers_table 
from category c left join
     answers a  
     on c.catid = a.catid and
        a.userid = 6
group by c.catid;
```

Note that I also changed the `sum()` to a `count()` -- `count()` automatically counts the number of times the argument is not `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon...Entirely forgot to keep that thing.Such a stupid I am.Thanks once again.Accepted.